# CentOS: detailed history of patch updates

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, patch-management, amazon-linux-2

e.g. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

> ...
>   chrony-3.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

Any ways to know what made the `-2` part in `3.2-2`? *I.e.* deltas between 3.2 and 3.2-2. That's no-brainer for [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/chrony) and [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chrony)

I'm using Amazon Linux 2, but wondering if there are any usable RPMs online containing a backport of the particular bugfix which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--changelog` option to `rpm` to view the package changelog.

For example:

```
rpm -q --changelog chrony | less
```

Comment: Or `rpm -qp chrony-3.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm --changelog | less` if it's before an actual installation